# Selecton on jquery ajax reply

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I am trying to understand what is preventing jquery from parsing my XML reply.

My code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax_gateway.php?request=agentdetails&agentid=6352",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        console.log(xml);
        alert($('agentname', xml).val());
        //$('input[name="agent_name"]').val($('agentname', xml).val());
    }   
});
```

I can see my intended XML logged to Chrome console. I checked headers, and my AJAX reply is sent with "Content-Type: text/xml". Unfortunately my alert is empty and if I try to do:

```
$(xml).("agentname").val()
```

I get error message in chrome JS console saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( ".
Am I missing something? I have several other function in my "ajax_gateway" and they are all working fine...

Edit:
My XML response:

> <?xml version="1.0"?>
>   <response><employee><agentname>My Name</agentname><agentteam>My Team</agentteam><agentphoneid>6352</agentphoneid></employee></response>

While papaiatis answered my question, would anyone bother to explain why:

```
$(xml).("agentname").text();
```

Is valid?

Comment: Can you please provide us the XML as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead.

`alert($('agentname', xml).text());`

*val() is used with form elements.*

Comment: Yeah, `val` is for form elements, not XML nodes. +1